# Implement optional functions in an abstract class

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have an abstract class that other classes can inherit from. I would like to have some functions that the class that inherits this class can optionally implement. In the code below, the function is `protected abstract`. This however requires that the class that is inheriting this class MUST implement these functions. Is there a way to make it so that the class that is inheriting can choose to implement the functions or not implement them?

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment {
    protected abstract fun getButton1Text(): String
    protected abstract fun getButton2Text(): String
}
```

Comment: only if you provide a default implementation in the abstract class

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is very simple, you just provide the default implementation like in the example below and your inheritors can `override` them:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment {

    open fun getButton1Text(): String {
        TODO("Your default implementation here")
    }

    open fun getButton2Text(): String {
        TODO("Your default implementation here")
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. But I did check the documentation at:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html
But it does not mention anything about this. Do you know if it's located somewhere else in the Kotlin docs?

Comment: None that I know of. :(

Comment: The doc for this is simply https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods . This here is a regular override, an abstract class doesn't need to have all its methods abstract. You just define a regular method in your abstract class for it to be overridden.

Comment: Those should be `open fun`, otherwise you won't be able to override them. And  they should have sensible default implementation as `TODO()` will crash the app.

Comment: I fixed the `open`. As for the `TODO()`, only the OP knows how a sensible implementation looks like so it is fine here.

Comment: Would this work for interfaces?